# I got the msg can't fork because you own this repository while share code to another git account multiple developers on same project

Tags: django, github, git-push, git-clone, git-fork

I got the message "cannot fork because you own this repository": I am trying to send the code on this repo to another account.

When I tried to share my code to another git account while working with multiple developers on same project, and I am new to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to send the code on this repo to another account

Then you need to fork that other account repository in order to initiate a pull request, notifying them of your new code to be merged back in their branch.

But if that other account does not have yet a repository, then the situation is reversed: they need to fork your own repository in order to get back your code, and to possibly contribute to your repository through pull request.